# If i Install Ubuntu on an External Drive using Wubi, does it do anything to my C: Drive?

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I have installed ubuntu using wubi on my old computer and Broke Windows (I had to re-install it). So excuse me If I am acting paranoid.

I was all ready to install ubuntu using Wubi then it hit me. Would WUBI Install GRUB on my C: or my Installation Drive (F:).

I will take any form of answer. I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

That's your solution. You must install Ubuntu with Windows. Before you installed Ubuntu instead Windows.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows